# Cells Backgroundcolor in the tableView with a lot of data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an array with several data, some of which are out of screen. I wrote a method, if click on a row its moves to the end of the array and the other moved up, in the same time I want to change the color of the selected row, do one know how to manage it??
Here the my try:

```
var dataSample = [....]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedItem = dataSample[indexPath.row]
    dataSample.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    dataSample.append(selectedItem)

    let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: dataSample.count - 1, inSelection: indexPath.selection)
    tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, toIndexPath: newIndexPath)

    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPath([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

and now comes my try to change the cell color

```
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(newIndexPath)
    cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor
```

but nothing happened and the color is not changed but,

if I scroll down and see the end of the array and then select some rows before the last, the row become to the wish color, but just on the bounds and not complete

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuh7M.png)

Comment: Where are you adding your code to change color of selected cell?

Comment: after tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPath([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

Comment: Did you try out what i had answered?

Comment: the problem is a lot of elements in the table, if i have few elements and see the end of the table, it works fine, but an many populated table brings the scrolling problems, that was my answer